# Wine and Sketchup

Tags: wine

After strenuous efforts I've managed to install Sketchup Make 16 (32 bit) in Ubuntu 18.04, which seems to work okay. Unfortunately there's a small problem that I can't fix. When you hover over the tool buttons the description of the tool is truncated and in a tiny box, so I can't read what the tool does. It's not a huge problem but it would be nice if I could resolve it.

Are there any Wine experts out there who know how to fix this? Not sure if it's a theme or a font problem, or something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the development version of wine - 3.8 - fixed this problem. It was a bug with the tooltips that is now fixed.

Once that's done I recommend using Winetricks to install .Net452 before installing Sketchup.

Comment: And just to clarify that on the WineTricks installer, .Net452 is actually listed as "dotnet452". In case someone is searching through the list alphabetically.